# How to test what is using page loading resources

Tags: google-chrome, xampp, firebug, loading

I use Google Web Development Tools and Firebug whilst developing WordPress themes to make sure there are no errors in the page and to check on the resources that the pages are using.

Recently using my own XAMPP, I have noticed that when I click a link in my WordPress Dashboard it takes a few seconds before the next page will load.

If there any way using Chrome Toils and Firebug that I can test the page loading progress to see where the page is "hanging" when loading.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the "Network" tab in either Chrome or Firefox developer tools. It may help you to investigate page and resource loading troubles.

Answer (score 0):

Give this tool a shot.

[tools.pingdom.com](https://tools.pingdom.com)

I find it very useful.